# java - searching for regular expression for credit card expiry that also checks if year is in the past

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am searching for a regular expression/function i can use in java such that i know that given MM/YYYY if the year is in the past it would fail validation.

i have this so far:

```
(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/20[1-9]{2}
```

but as you can see this means 201* is still valid.  so 2015 would be valid etc. i want from the current year onward would be valid. any year in the past should not be valid.  How can i do this ?

Comment: instead regex use the ***Luhn-Algorithmus*** and ***Date/Time*** API

Comment: Why do people insist on using regex where it's not appropriate?

Comment: Parse the element to LocalDate and then check if year is before or after current year, bettr

Comment: Better yet... `java.time.YearMonth`.

Comment: how you get the current year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LocalDate` :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate date= LocalDate.parse("02/04/2017", dtf );
    System.out.println(isYearPast(date));                                    // false
    System.out.println(isYearPast(LocalDate.parse("02/04/2012", dtf )));     // true
}

public static boolean isYearPast(LocalDate date){
    return date.getYear() < LocalDate.now().getYear();
}
```

---

Or more basic element manipulation :

```
String date ="04/2012";
boolean past = Integer.parseInt(date.split("/")[1]) < LocalDate.now().getYear();
System.out.println(past);   // true
```

All will return a `boolean` value, as if you were using a `regex` that will tell you if match or not

The problem with `regex` is that you would to refesh the `pattern` each year and also it will be bad to detail the `int` accepted like ok for 2017 and not 2016

Answer (score 1):

In general I don't recommend on using Regex where it is not necessary, but still, the best answer I can think of is to do something like this:

```
(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/201[7-9]|202[0-9]
```

**NOTE** that validation is only on the *year*, and a date like `1/2017` is valid. If you want to solve this you have to have a case for each previous month in 2017.

Also, I really recommend on using `LocalDate` as @azro suggested.